# yii2 :how to add multi rules for access of behaviors

Tags: php, yii2

i want use multi rules in one behaviors.

how can i solve this problem ?

```
   public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                    [
                    'actions' => ['file'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['user2'],
                ],
                    [
                    'actions' => ['file'],
                    'allow' => false,
                    'roles' => ['document'],
                ],
            ],
```

Comment: can you elaborate your requirements. as i understood file should be accessible only to user2. is this u required.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not quite clear to me, but I think you want to do something like this...

Extend the AccesRule class and implement how a role should be accessed

```
class AccessRule extends \yii\filters\AccessRule {
protected function matchRole($user)
    {
        if (empty($this->roles)) {
            return true;  // no roles defined = access ok
        }
        foreach ($this->roles as $role) {
            // return true if role is allowed based on $user (define your logic)
        }
        return false; // no match, ie no access
    }
}
```

Then add this new rule class to you AccessControl...

```
'access' => [
    'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
    'ruleConfig' => ['class' => '\my\namespace\AccessRule'],
    'rules' => [
        ...
    ],
]
```

Note: Code is not tested.